# Can Physical Address be accessed with php or javascript.?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Can we access physical address (Mac Address) with php or javascript?

For my site I have to identify each system (if on same network or different) uniquely.

Thanks

Comment: Physical address of the client??? No way. For the server: You will have to use some system software (eg. ifconfig/arp) and get the address from the result.

Comment: Only of the `next hop`.

Comment: How I can identify each system uniquely? Except IP address what I can use for this?

Comment: Is using cookies an option? You could store a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at https://panopticlick.eff.org/index.php?action=log&js=yes and try to do the same. It will give you a pretty uniq identification of each browser who come to you're website.

This can help you to http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
$mac = system('arp -an'); echo '<pre>'; print_r($mac);
```

Hope this will help...

Keep clam & Keep coding